# Removing whitespace in python

Tags: python, whitespace

I am using python to read headers from SAC but am having trouble removing whitespace. I want to remove the space before the next station name e.g RPZ, TOZ, URZ. This is my code:

```
for s in stations:
    tr=st[0]
    h=tr.stats
    stnm = h.station
    tt = h.sac.t1

    print>>f,stnm, 'P', '1', tt,
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
DSZ P 1 53.59RPZ P 1 72.80TOZ P 1 40.25URZ P 1 32.26
```

Then to go onto a new line after `32.26`. This is why I have the comma after `tt`.

However it currently outputs like this with the unwanted space before `RPZ`, `TOZ` and `URZ`:

```
DSZ P 1 53.59 RPZ P 1 72.80 TOZ P 1 40.25 URZ P 1 32.26
```

Any suggestions? I have tried `x.strip()`, but I get the

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `print` statement is adding the spaces; if you want the space to be dropped, don't `print` but use `f.write()` instead:

```
f.write('{} P 1 {}'.format(stnm, tt))
```

This uses string formatting with [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to create the same output format, but now no space will be written following the `tt` value.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative to Martin's answer, you could also (for Python 2.6+ import and) use the print function, something like;

```py
# import only needed for Python2
from __future__ import print_function      

print(stnm, 'P', '1', tt, end='', file=f)
```